# How to redirect page based on url in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

This (service) is a common controller file for admin and teacher.

This controller is routing like, admin/books and teacher/books.
so if it session expire then want to redirect their login pages admin/login or teacher/login.

how to possible in codeigniter?

```
public function books(){
    if($this->session->userdata('logged_in_admin') || $this->session->userdata('logged_in_teacher')) {
    // common function.
    }else{
      // redirect('admin/login') /* for admin/books */
      // redirect('teacher/login') /* for teacher/books */
    }
}
```

Comment: I would add redirect_url on my session array on login based on user level then just call the array to redirect

Comment: yes it will not work some cases. when i directly go this url then it not work

Comment: Ok why do you need two login pages? you can have 1 login page and redirect users based on their roles to the specif folders but have 1 common login page

Comment: @VIJAY use `redirect` like this `redirect('teacher/login', 'location');` hope that will work.

Comment: Why don't you make use of cookie.? Save logged in user role in cookies, then check it to make decision.

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile client want two separate login pages so the reason for separate login

Comment: @VIJAY that is pointless speak to your client.. it does not make sense to have separate login but they all go to the same function on success login

Comment: @saddam you means? redirect like this redirect('teacher/login', 'location');

Comment: do you have two separate controllers on `admin ` and one on `teacher` folder respectivelly?

Comment: @VIJAY yes I mean to redirect with `location`.

Comment: @saddam but it not work

Comment: @VIJAY let us know you've two separate controller for  `admin` and `teacher`.

Comment: yes two separate controller for admin and teacher

Comment: common functions are in service controller

Comment: @VIJAY share your controller as well, so that I can test it on my side.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got answer by using uri segments, so this work for me.

```
redirect($this->uri->segment(1).'/login');
```